# Create excel using poi raise exception

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-poi

I'm using eclipse to create excel file from Oracle database using POI. If data set is small no problem. But if it is huge we got following exception.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

```
My heap setting is. -Xms512m -Xmx1024m
```

If I increase max size to 2048m we got

```
Could not create Java Virtual Machine.
```

error. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to check what is the capacity of your operating system (is it a 32 bit system or 64 bit system)

As far as my information:

32-bit JVMs which expect to have a single large chunk of memory cannot use more than 4 Gb (since that is the 32 bit limit which also applies to pointers). This includes Sun and - I'm pretty sure - also IBM implementations. I do not know if e.g. JRockit or others have a large memory option with their 32-bit implementations.

If you expect to be hitting this limit you should strongly consider starting a parallel track validating a 64-bit JVM for your production environment so you have that ready for when the 32-bit environment breaks down. Otherwise you will have to do that work under pressure, which is never nice.

```
Extra information:
On normal consumer versions of Windows, the limit is 2GB 
which is equivalent to 2048M. On Linux and server versions 
of Windows (32-bit) 
the limit is 3GB per process.
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it based on the guidelines [from](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#sxssf).